# How can I show my query results on one line?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I move this line? I can't view the results properly right now.

[image]

Comment: If you're gonna downvote, atleast let me know why.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in this site, because it's not about programming. It is also tagged as "Oracle SQL", when in fact your problem is with the SQL Developer interface. You can try the Oracle forums at community.oracle.com.

Comment: @andrechalom - SQL Developer arguably comes under "software tools commonly used by programmers" which would potentially make it on-topic. It's debatable though...

Answer (score 4):

The default line size in SQL Developer (and SQL*Plus) is 80 characters. Your output exceeds that so it's wrapping each row in the result set into multiple lines in the script output window.

The first fix is to increase the linesize:

```
set linesize 200
```

... or any suitable number. You just need it to be wide enough for your data. If you make it too big you may have to scroll sideways to see all of the columns, though that depends on their data types.

You can also make the columns narrower, but only really if you know that all of the values in them are shorter than the minimum:

```
column name format a20
column friend format a20
```

If you make that to narrow individual values will still wrap onto the next line.

Most, but not all, [SQL*Plus `set` commands](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG060) work in SQL Developer too. (You might want to investigate `set pagesize`, for example). You can also use [an SQL Developer-specific command](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/):

```
set sqlformat ansiconsole
```

which automatically eliminates a lot of whitespace for you; but you may still need to set linesize.

---

Dave Michener suggested you were (only) referring to the vertical dotted line in the screenshot, which is reasonable as that's what your arrow points to. But that is just a visual guideline, and has no real effect; it's more useful in the worksheet so you can see when a line of code gets too long.

Although it's displayed in the script output window as well, it does even less there, and it's completely independent of the linesize setting. You can move the line from the preferences:

[image]

But if you increase that and leave linesize at the default 80, the output will still be wrapped as it was before. You'll just have more whitespace between the output and the line.

Comment: I think @SJacobs is referring to the vertical bar in that picture, not the width of the SQL output.

Comment: @DaveMichener - maybe so, from the screenshot, but moving it has no effect on how the output is displayed. I've added how to do that anyway. Thanks.

Comment: No matter which `sqlformat` I choose I always get items on separate lines... Tried changing `linesize` too, but for some reason it doesn't get changed at all. I only have read-only access to the DB, but I just want to change my output view, not DB settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem that my results were shown in multiple lines. I realised that Sql Developer runs the queries as code snippets when using "F5", and runs the queries normally when using "Ctrl+Enter". I was able to see the results properly when using "Ctrl+Enter".

If you prefer to use "F5" for running the queries normally, then you can switch this in the preferences -> shortcut keys window.